# Survfit function in R to score a new dataset

Tags: survival, prediction, cox-model

I have built a cox proportional hazards model in the R survival package.  I want to score new data set using this model.  I thought the survfit function would doing this using survfit(original model, newdata), but it only seems to predict only the outcomes for the original data, not the original model using the new data.

Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: If you're after predictions of survival probability, the function `survest` [`survival`-package] (or predictSurvProb [`pec`-package]) is very useful for this.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `predict` function.  According to the `survival` package documentation there is a `predict.coxph` function, so when that package is loaded and you pass `predict` a `coxph` object it will use it for prediction with your new data.  See `?predict.coxph` for the additional arguments.